# Alterar fundo da div no visited

Tags: html, css

Estou querendo alterar o fundo da `div`, quando a pessoa esta visitando aquele link.

Tentei usar o `visited` mas não esta funcionando.

HTML

```
<div class="e divFloatLeaft">
            <h:link styleClass="menu" value="Página Principal" outcome="index" />
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.e:hover {
   background-image:url(./img/fundo-laranja.jpg) !important;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;   
}

.e:visited {
   background-image:url(./img/fundo-laranja.jpg) !important;
   background-repeat: repeat-x; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar `.menu:visited`, porque tal seletor é utilizado para links que foram visitados, utilizando o endereço do hyperlink. No seu exemplo, você está utilizando a classe do elemento `div`.

Comment: então ficaria `.div:visited`?

Comment: Não, não. Você precisa usar o `:visited` no elemento do hyperlink, e não da `div`.

Comment: hmmm e como aplicaria o efeito na div se estaria usando o evento do link?

Comment: Você poderia utilizar JavaScript, mas com CSS não é possível.

Comment: ok obrigado, vou ver se acho algo em jquery para me ajudar nisso.